# Restart Springboard without locking screen?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

Is there any way to restart the Springboard programmatically, but prevent the iPhone from turning on its screen lock following this?

Have tried switching off the screen lock in Settings, but it'll still kick in after a Springboard restart.

(The phone is jailbroken.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**As of iPhone OS 3.x**, You can bypass the lock screen with `notify_post("com.apple.language.changed")`.

---

This method no longer work in **iOS 5.x** because the system now checks whether the language is actually changed before respringing.

However, you could do the following to achieve the same effect:

1. Set the preference `SBLanguageRestart` of `com.apple.springboard` to **true** (using [CFPreferencesSetAppValue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFPreferencesUtils/Reference/reference.html) and [CFPreferencesAppSynchronize](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFPreferencesUtils/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFPreferencesAppSynchronize), for instance, or directly changing `/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.springboard.plist`)
2. Kill SpringBoard.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working (anymore).  I have a 4.3.3 iPhone 4, and while calling notify_post("com.apple.language.changed") does not cause a visual respringing, where the screen locks afterwards, it also does not cause SpringBoard to reload its settings.  Using 'ps' at the command line also shows the same process ID.  So, basically, this isn't restarting SpringBoard is any sense.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Not really a programming question but no, you can't stop the lock screen.