# Respring application for jailbroken iPod Touch

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

So I have a third generation iPod Touch, with ios 4.2.1 and it's jailbroken. I'm using SSH to transfer files between it and my computer, but my problem is that when ever I add a file to it, and I want to take a look at it, I need to restart or respring my iPod before I can see it. So I've thought of a very tiny app placed at the homescreen, that resprings the iPod. My problems is that I don't know **anything** about coding for apple. Is there a 'one line solution' for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you mean by transferring **files**.  Are you referring to transferring **apps**?

If so, you can make newly installed (via SSH copy) apps appear on the home screen by SSHing in to your phone and doing this

```bsh
>ssh mobile@ipod
>uicache
```

or

```bsh
>ssh root@ipod
>su mobile -c uicache
```

depending on whether you have your iPod setup to allow logins as `root` or `mobile`.  Obviously, in my above example, you must have the IP address of your iPod mapped to the hostname `"iPod"`, or else use IP addresses.

Another option that you may or may not be aware of is the **SBSettings** app itself.  If you install that from Cydia, it has a really nice toggle to simply respring.  That's not much more work than having a "tiny app" to respring (one extra touch, I guess).

If you are writing an Objective-C iOS app, and you want to do this **programmatically** (which wasn't 100% clear in the question), then [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2021332/119114).  And see here for [information on using `notify_post`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/notify_post.3.html)

Comment: I mean that I can use any SSH client to transfer anything from the ipod to my computer and vice versa. As you probably know, Apple has made transferring the music from the ipod very hard, but SSH can transfer the files without questions. **And to the point** Yes, I want to write and Objective-C app, and do this programmatically.

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen, ok, that can certainly be done.  However, when you say "you don't know anything about coding for Apple", that presents some problems.  Have you built an iOS "hello world" program?  That certainly would be a place to start.  I don't think I'd recommend making my first iOS app a jailbreak app.  Baby steps.  But, when you do get your first app built, you can use the information in my last paragraph above, or what's in Fire30's answer.

Comment: No I haven't done a "Hello world" app. I just read that iPhone developping can be only made via Mac? So I can't use notepad to just copy paste a few lines?

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen, normal iOS development requires a Mac.  You can do iOS *open* development without Apple's tools at all, and you could do this on a Linux box, or I guess a Windows box.  This is really a separate problem.  You could look [here for some info](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Main_Page) or just google for "developing iOS applications without Xcode, using the open *toolchain*".  I have to reiterate that this is really not advisable.  Learning to develop iOS apps the way Apple intends should come first, and stuff like this should come second.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this will be the last time I develop an iOS app, so let's just do it the **easy** way :)

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen, Yeah, unfortunately, Apple doesn't always make stuff easy.  I think it  is pretty easy to write a hello world iOS app **if you have a Mac**, and adding a couple lines of code (either my solution, or Fire30's) isn't a ton of extra complexity.  But, if you want to develop on a non-Mac platform, **easy** is basically no longer an option :(

Answer (score 3):

If you want an app that just kills springboard, then in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

just add this:

```
system("killall SpringBoard");
```

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen, when you build your first iOS app with Xcode, it will generate the equivalent of a "main" program.  The traditional C (language) `main` in Objective-C will start an app with the help of an Objective-C *app delegate*.  The app delegate class is generated for you by Xcode, and you will see in there the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, which is where Fire30 is suggesting you put the `system()` call.